# jQuery: More elegant if/else with selectors

Tags: jquery

I spit out this type of code frequently:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'X') {
    $('#something').show();
}
else {
    $('#something').hide();
}
```

I'm not crazy about having $('#something') appear twice. Is there a more elegant way of expressing this?

[Update] I phrased the question badly - I'm looking for a general solution, not just show/hide (and therefore toggle). For the general case of taking different actions on a selected element(s) based on a conditional, is there a more elegant construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the general question of not having '#something' appear twice, I'd say it's more readable to have it twice. otherwise, you wind up with the following:

```
$('#something')[$(this).val()=='X'?'show':'hide']();
```

Answer (score 8):

#### [`toggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle#switch)

> Toggle displaying each of the set of
>   matched elements based upon the switch
>   (true shows all elements, false hides
>   all elements).
>
> If the switch is true,
>   toggle makes them hidden (using the
>   hide method). If the switch is false,
>   toggle makes them shown (using the
>   show method).

```
var result = ($(this).val() != 'X');
$('#something').toggle(result);
```

or shorter

```
$('#something').toggle('X' != $(this).val());
```

Comment: Your logic is backwards from the question, but the method is right.