# jquery if (value)... else avoiding "duplicate selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a notification on PhpStorm that "Duplicate JQuery Selector" for a JQuery `if...else` conditional based on a value and then updating that value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#forgotten').click(function () {
        if($('#button').val() === 'Login') {
            $('#button').val('Send New Password');
        }
        else {
            $('#button').val('Login');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

PhpStorm tells me

> Duplicated jQuery selector 
> Inspection info: Checks that jQuery selectors are used in an efficient way. It warns about duplicated selectors which could be cached and optionally about attribute and pseudo-selectors usage

- Does this really matter? (I suspect not, it's micro-optimisation)
- Is there a better way of writing this code (I suspect so)?
- What is this better way?

## Attempts:

```
if($('#button').val() === 'Login') {
        $(this).val('Send New Password');
    }
    else {
        $(this).val('Login');
    }
```

The above code using `this` doesn't work; It seems that the JQuery isn't aware of what `this` is because it's not an invocation.

Attempt two is to use [This useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853754/jquery-more-elegant-if-else-with-selectors):

> ```
>   $('#something')[$(this).val()=='X'?'show':'hide']();
> ```

But I can't see the syntax of how to apply this to swapping the value.

```
$('#button')[$(this).val() === 'Login'?$(this).val('Send New Password'):$(this).val('Login')];
```

The above attempt does not make the change expected (and does not give any console notices).

So, how do I do it; how do I write the original IF statement without repeating the reference?

Comment: `var btn = $('#button'); btn.val( btn.val() === 'Login' ? 'Send New Password' : 'Login');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a jquery has (some, minor) overhead, so is not the *most* efficient.  Your first code could be written as:

```
var btn = $("#button");
if (btn.val() === 'Login') {
    btn.val('Send New Password');
}
else {
    btn.val('Login');
}
```

while, in this case, it's a micro-optimisation, if you were doing this 1000s of times with very complicated selectors, it can save a lot of time to only run the jquery selection once.

Regarding your other attempts, using `this` will only make sense if `this` has relevant context, eg if inside an event:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
    var btn = $(this); 
    ...
```

---

In the case of `.val()` (and many other jquery functions (but not all)) a callback can be provided which is called for each entry in the jquery collection.

> https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function
>
> A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

In your case, this becomes:

```
 $("#button").val(function(i, v) { return v === "Login" ? "Send new" : "login" });
```

This will run the callback function on each item in the collection provided by the selector, so very useful if you want to run against multiple items with different results on each, example:

```js
$(".button").val(function(i, v) { return v === "Login" ? "Send new" : "login" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Login"></input>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Login"></input>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Not Login"></input>
```

Comment: So it looks like simply saving the identifier to a variable and referencing the variable rarther than the identifier is the solution.... but then when the identifier (`$('#button')`) value changes, this won't automatically update the variable (`btn`) so I'd need to preserve this with an `.on(change` type of call?

Comment: Yes, it's *a* solution - the idea is to only set the variable (`var btn = $("#button")` ) *directly* before you need it, eg within an event handler - not in doc.ready at startup / global - it's only for short-term use to reduce the number of DOM selections.  In your case from 2 lookups to just 1, but can be a lot more.  You shouldn't need to "manage" it with other event handlers.  (get a few questions here on SO with that problem).

Comment: I've also provided details on the `.val(function)` overload, which doesn't require a new variable or "caching" lookup as termed in your original error message.

Comment: Your additional update looks exactly like the sort of thing the notice is expecting, however running it on my code, it only works on the *first* usage, and does not work for continued usage.  I have further updated my question to add scopem, if that helps.  Cheers

Comment: Ok there was some sort of copy mistake, yes, your additional answer works every time.

Comment: You might have used `#button` which only gets the first matching id - in the snipper I've used `.button` and `class=button` to select multiple

Comment: If you can clarify your answer to show `There is also an alternative version....` is the one that works, then I can set this as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Not all jquery functions have a `function` callback overload (eg .val, .html, .addClass do, but .toggle doesn't) - your error message is simply stating that you've used `$("#button")` more than once.

Comment: Does the `var = $("#button")` not work for you?  That's a direct replacement of your original code to remove the "you've used the same selector twice" warning.  If you're going to do more than set .val() then you probably want to cache the lookup in a variable

Comment: So, in short, putting the function inside the function call solves the duplication notice, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `$("#button")` jQuery searches the document and gets the corresponding DOM element. So you can try to assign the selection to a variable as followings to avoid the repetition of the search:

```
var btn = $('#button');

if(btn.val() === 'Login') {
   btn.val('Send New Password');
}
else {
   btn.val('Login');
}
```